# Angular - identify scope or controller

Tags: angularjs, scope, controllers

I am new to Angular (1 week) and would like to know how to identify a particular controller within a view. I have a page with 5 separate stopwatches running that currently accept no keystrokes. Each of these stopwatches uses exactly the same controller, but in their own  and are happy enough to run separately as I wanted. I would like to be able to use keystrokes to activate only one of these controllers eg if I hit A it would simulate pressing the "lap" button on the A stopwatch. But as each controller is the same name, I cannot determine how to send this keystroke to the correct stopwatch. I may be using Angular incorrectly so any advice would be appreciated. TIA. Jeremy

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle? Events will trigger at the closest controller. If the controller is isolated, like in a directive, you'll have to trigger an emit to notify parent controllers. If the controllers are siblings, then you could broadcast the message it use a service. If you can post some code, i could help you more.

Comment: I have added a reduced fiddle showing 2 stopwatches only. I normally have 5 across the page. All I want to do is add the ability to press a key (A) and this will activate the Lap key in A grade, B will active Lap in B grade etc. This is because the computer is used outside and it is a PITA trying to find the mouse pointer quickly. I may be doing things incorrectly, but this is my first Angular app. The fiddle is at (http://jsfiddle.net/3Fxhu/)

Answer (score 1):

Normally; a view wouldn't try to access a controller directly.  You can associate a view element with a controller using the ng-controller tag, like this:

```
<div ng-controller="myController"></div>
```

It sounds like your "stopwatch" really is five separate instances of the same component; in which case I suggest you consider building a [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).  A directive is like the Angular version of a component which can include display code and JavaScript code.  The directive can have a controller defined and when you use the directive in your page there will be five independent instances of it; so the pressing the lap button in one should not affect the others.

Answer (score 0):

Since your keyboard input is not linked to a focused element, you would have to bind to `body` `keydown keypress` events. For this create a directive like

```
app.directive('keyCapture', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $('body').bind("keydown", function (event) {
            if(event.which === attrs.filter[0]) {
                scope.$apply(function (){
                    scope.callMethod();
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

You can use this directive now with

```
<div id='timer' key-capture="" filter="a"></div>
<div id='timer' key-capture="" filter="e"></div>
```

The controller should have the method `callMethod` which this directive would call correctly.

If you can use isolated scope, you can pass this method as part of scope object using `&`